# Pyinstaller failed to execute script: FileNotFoundError: No file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\etc'

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, librosa

I have a python file I am converting to `exe`  via `Pyinstaller`. The coversion runs fine with no error, however when I run the exe file I get error in line 13 of the python file (line is import librosa). Then I get a bunch of files and then a

```
FileNotFoundError: No file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\johnny\\Appdata\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI70722\\librosa\\util\\example_data\\registry.txt'.
```

Also the python file itself runs fine.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

PyInstaller tries to find all the dependencies, however this file is not imported but loaded so it misses it. You can simply force it to add it:

```
--add-data [path to your python]/Lib/site-packages/librosa/util/example_data;librosa/util/example_data
```

With The full command be like :

```
pyinstaller --onefile [YourScript].py --add-data [path to your python]/Lib/site-packages/librosa/util/example_data/registry.txt;librosa/util/example_data
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to specify the data files as PyInstaller hooks.

1. Create a folder "extra-hooks", and in it a file "hook-librosa.py"
2. paste these 2 lines in "extra-hooks/hook-librosa.py":

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('librosa')
```

3. Then tell PyInstaller where to locate this file with adding 1 of the following to your PyInstaller command:

> --additional-hooks=extra-hooks

> --additional-hooks-dir "[PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT]/axtra-hooks"

The 2nd one worked for me, and I was using `auto-py-to-exe`, built on `PyInstaller`.

Comment: Also, hook-librosa.py can be pasted in /hooks directly, and from build log, it works, (Of course this is not a good coding habit) .

Answer (score -3):

I guess the file doesn't exist. Open a `file manager` and copy the directory.

Comment: I know the file doesn't exist, that's what the error says but my question is why it doesn't exist

Answer (score -3):

In the `PyInstaller`, you should type in the python file's name and then `--onefile`. It makes an `.EXE` file (if you are on windows) with all the imported files within. You can learn more here: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html