# Error when tying to execute the .exe generated by pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, py2exe, librosa

I just finished a project and want to convert it to a executable.
When using pyinstaller with the command `pyinstaller --onefile Music_sorter_by_Fabrice_Schöneberger.py` it compiles without an error. But when executing the file I get the following:

```
  File "Music_sorter_by_Fabrice_Schöneberger.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "librosa\__init__.py", line 215, in <module>
  File "lazy_loader\__init__.py", line 243, in attach_stub
ValueError: Cannot load imports from non-existent stub 'C:\\Users\\fabri\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI157482\\librosa\\__init__.pyci'
[1588] Failed to execute script 'Music_sorter_by_Fabrice_Sch÷neberger' due to unhandled exception!
```

The folders `...\_MEI157482\\librosa\\__init__.pyci` don't exist (the before does) and if I look within the librosa installation I can't find a file named `__init__.pyci`. I have a `__init__.pyi` and `__init__.py`. I don't find such a file online so I hope someone here can help me.

Edit: The problem is not pyinstaller specific. py2exe has the exact same problem, that I can't find a `__init___.pyci`. I think i might be that the installers can't complile librosa correctly?

Comment: This sound like it's an issue with [hidden imports](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports).

Comment: @MarceloPaco I've tried using --hidden-import=librosa but that didn't do anything
I've also tried --collect-all librosa and the extra hook thing from this post's answere by belferink1996: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218655/pyinstaller-failed-to-execute-script-filenotfounderror-no-file-or-directory
Nothing worked

Comment: What about this [issue comment](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/538#issuecomment-378420044)?

Comment: Good tip but also no. I tried what the comment described but I get another error ```SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape``` with pointing to the comma in datas.

Answer (score 1):

add an specific hook for librosa worked for me, using Auto-py-to-exe.

Create a folder named "extra-hooks", and in it a file "hook-librosa.py"
paste these 2 lines in "extra-hooks/hook-librosa.py":

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
datas = collect_data_files('librosa')
```

Then tell where to locate this file with adding the following command in Settings>Manually Provide Options:

```
--additional-hooks-dir "[PATH_TO_YOUR_PROJECT]/axtra-hooks"
```

source of the solution: https://github.com/librosa/librosa/issues/538

Comment: As alternative to `--additional-hooks-dir`, you can specify the path to your `extra-hooks` directory in the pyinstaller `.spec` file in the field `hookspath`